# Outlook Addin, When Loading Error Ribbon_GetDCVisible

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an outlook VSTO addin, I get the error `Ribbon_GetDCVisible  Exception occurred while calling the function GetVisisble` when it loads.  Yhe stack trace shows my last function called is the ThisAddIn_StartUp() handler and it is e mpty.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I just made a blank outlook 2013 addin and it gave the same errors.  So obviously something is wrong there.

EDIT2:

Reinstalled office, no luck.  Even using XML, and a blank addin I get `Ribbon_GetDCVisible  Exception occurred while calling the function GetVisisble` when opening a mail item with any addin created with VS even if no code  has been added to it at all.

Comment: What error do you get? Could you be more specific? What code and ribbon XML do you have?

Comment: Add try catch and debug each getVisible ribbon callback. Post the getVisible callbacks that raise exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to rebuild and check startup code.  My problem was a duplicate key in dict during startup.